# Configuration file best practices node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, config

I'm working on a node.js project where a lot of modules require a configuration file. At the moment I'm requiring the config file in each module, is it the best way of doing it? I've thought about setting the config as a global but it looks "dirty".
Here's the file for now (do not mind the structure for now, it's still in development)

```
{
  "root" :  "undefined",
  "jwtAuthentication": {
    "appSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "expiration": "48h"
  },
  "authorization": {
    "guestActions": [ "signup" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: show us the config file.

Comment: @JoeLloyd Edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I set my project structure:

```
  module1
   --controllers
   --services
   --middleware
   --config
  module2
   --controllers
   --services
   --middleware
   --config
  shared
   --config
   --services
```

In shared/config I set global configuration and in module{i} configuration specific to that module.